# How to change pager position of Kendo UI grid from left to right

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, position, pager

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I use Kendo UI grid. I want to change pager position from left below grid to right below grid.

I read many topic but they talk about change pager from bottom to top. I try to use HTMLAttribute, use style :
- text-align:right
- align-content: space-end

I try to modify Kendo grid pager css : k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager 
But none of them work.

Anyone here know how to solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the `.k-pager-wrap>.k-link` select is who brings them to the left you can do

```
<style>
    body .k-pager-wrap > .k-link {
      float: right;
    }

    body .k-grid .k-pager-numbers {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```

`body` selector is added to prevail kendo style

but it leads to a problem, that next/previous page buttons is on the wrong sides due to the nature of float

Comment: I try this <style>
    body .k-pager-wrap > .k-link {
        float: right;
    }
</style> but it won't work

Comment: @scvn80 I've updated my answer, but it seems to be something that overrides css rules. Try to add `!important` to the `float: right !important;`